# Unable to use a formula to conditionally format a range of cells if two cells have same value

Tags: excel-formula

I realize this is a simple question, but regardless of reading 20-30 responses, I still can't make this work.  I have two columns,`D4:D1849` and `G4:G1849`, which may or may not have the same values.  I just want to highlight d4 and g4 if both columns have different values.

I tried doing a conditional format using cell value `<> $G4&$D4`, applied to `=$D$4:$G$4`, which seemed to work, but I obviously don't want to do that formatting for 1800 cells.  So, I tried to add a range, through various forms, none of which worked.  I don't understand why I just can't add `G4:G1849&D4:D1849` as the cells to check, and then apply the formatting to `-$D4:D1849&G4:G1849`.

This probably too easy, and i'm just not getting the syntax right or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear from your description of the problem what you would like to accomplish if one or both of the cells in columns D and G are blank (empirically speaking, they would not be equal if one was blank but would be equal if both were). I'll try to cover both scenarios as well as the text vs numbers possibilities.

First, clear out any previous Conditional Formatting attempts with *Home, Conditional Formatting, Clear Rules*. Tap `F5` and when the `GoTo` dialog opens type `G4:G1849,D4:D1849` into the *Reference* box and click OK. This will select the D4:D1849,G4:G1849 range with D4 as the active cell. Choose *Home, Conditional Formatting, New Rule* and use the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* option and supply one of the following for *Format values where this formula is true*.

To apply the formatting rules when there are numbers in both column D and column G,

`=AND(COUNT($D4,$G4)=2, $D4-$G4)`

To apply the formatting rules when there are numbers or text in both column D and column G,

`=AND(COUNTA($D4,$G4)=2, $D4<>$G4)`

To apply the formatting rules when at least one of the cells in columns D and G are non-blank,

`=AND(COUNTA($D4,$G4), $D4<>$G4)`